# Prevent Animation Tab from changing the position of an object

Tags: unity, animation, vector, transformation

I am quite new to Unity. I am using the latest version. When I try to make a **door open animation**, it goes well with rotation. But when I add the position property it takes it to the `Vector3(40,12.5,7.5)` instead of `(10,2.5,15)` at the first frame. I try to change the value but it reverts after I write.

Comment: Try creating a new empty project in Unity, and see if you can reproduce this problem. Record every step you take along the way, so you can share them here and we can follow the same steps to produce exactly the problem you're seeing. That will give us what we need to unambiguously identify the problem, and test solutions to be sure you get working answers.

Comment: Please include the specific Unity version - the 'latest version' today will not necessarily be the 'latest version' tomorrow & the information is more likely to help future readers others if they can easily tell which version you were referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, but this sounds like you still have your animation preview toggled on while trying to edit values.

[image: Preview toggled on]

If this is the case, you might also notice that the input field for the value you are trying to edit has a blue background. Click the preview button to toggle it.

Make sure that when you are trying to edit the values to a keyframe, the recording mode is toggled ON, and when you try to edit the values of an object while not influencing an animation, both preview and recording are toggled OFF

If this is not the issue you are currently encountering, please provide screenshots and a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Fix Worked! Or Silly Question from me